# How can I see a dynamically assigned port from within a docker container?

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a server application that takes a few minutes to fully startup and be ready to process requests.  I want to have the container register itself with an NGINX load-balancer when it knows that it has started, but I don't know how to determine the port docker assigned to the container (I'm starting lots of these with docker run -P).  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

You cannot talk to the docker daemon by default from inside the container and you shouldn't try to. From the containers perspective, it is running a process on port `80` or whatever is the default of the webapp.

To determine the port assigned to a container, you can either use the `docker port` or the `docker inspect` command from the host running the container.

`docker port my_webapp_1`
This returns the list of mapped ports of the container.

`docker inspect my_webapp_1`

This returns a json in which you can find `NetworkSettings` which lists you all the ports of the containers and which ports of the host they are mapped to.

You can run an additional process which reads this data from `docker port` or `docker inspect` and updates your nginx config.

Comment: Thanks, that's not ideal, because it's not that easy to tell from outside the process if it's ready to start receiving requests.  It would be much easier if the newly started process could somehow inform docker that it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hostname` (which is equal to the container ID) from inside the container and send it to the host. The host will then use `docker inspect` on that hostname to get the port.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "send it to the host".  How do I do that?

Comment: @IanG in the OP you wrote "I want to have the container register itself with an NGINX load-balancer when it knows that it has started" so I assumed you have a mechanism for that. How were you planning to do that if you knew the port number?